# Making static class data serializable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, static

Consider the following:

```
public class myClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int i; //<- value set from inspector

    static myClass()
    {
        Awake();
    }

    private static void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log(i); //<- Error CS0120
    }
}
```

This would throw me an error `error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'myClass.i'`

I could then (according to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120)) try to write it in another way:

```
public class myClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int i;

    static myClass()
    {
        Awake();
    }

    private static void Awake()
    {
        var mc = new myClass();
        Debug.Log(mc.i); //<- NullReferenceException
    }
}
```

But that would throw me error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object myClass.Awake ()`.

Meaning that I cannot serialize static variables? Is there a workaround? I'm sorry but I'm still getting used to C# and if you could also give me a brief theoretical reason why it doesn't work it would help me greatly in understanding. Thanks!

Comment: classes of type `MonoBehaviour` may not be instantiated using `new` and my not have any constrcutor.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a workaround that would allow me to serialize the data but still not throwing a CS0120 error?

Comment: Why do you need a `static` method **at all**? Especially for Unity's message methods like `Awake` it makes absolutely no sense to be `static` .. what is your usecase? And if you say this class is supposed to be a data container .. does it need to be a `MonoBehaviour` anyway? Note that this issue here has nothing to do with `serializable` or not ..

Comment: You might be right... I initially used `MonoBehaviour` because I didn't know about the `static` attribute. If I remove the MonoBehaviour, will I still be able to initialize the values inside? I've not worked much with non-MonoBehaviour classes...

Comment: @derHugo that was it, I've removed the MonoBehaviour and it works now. If you reply below I can accept the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Your issue has nothing to do with a field being `serializable` or not.

It is rather related to your instanced class field `i` not being accessible from a `static` context. As the error states you would need an instance of your class in order to access it there **but**

As also mentioned classes of type `MonoBehaviour` are not allowed to have any constructor and may not be instanciated via the `new` keyword in Unity. The only allowed ways of creating instances of components is via `Instantiate`, `AddComponent` or via the constructor of e.g. `new GameObject("someName", typeof(YOUR_COMPONENT));`.

---

You don't need a Singleton for what you want. It sounds like you actually would want to go this way round:

```
public class myClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This one you set via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private int _i; 

    // This is now a read-only property
    // That can only be set by this class
    public static int i { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Your instance can always access its static fields
        // So this way you can assign the value
        i = _i;
    }
}
```

---

In general we would need more input in order to figure out your actual usecase here. It is also possible that you could rather use an entirely static class like e.g.

```
public static class myClass
{
    public static int i = 42;
}
```

this makes your field not serialized but simply accessible from everywhere without the need of an instance in the Scene. You would simply access it from another `MonoBehaviour` like e.g.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(myClass.i);
    }
}
```

Or you might want to make your class not static at all but rather access it through the correct reference like

```
[Serializable]
public class myClass
{
    public int i = 42;
}

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Since it is tagged Serializable and now serialized in the Inspector
    // an instance is created for this field automatically
    [SerializedField] private myclass _myClass;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log(_myclass.i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unity can only serialize a specific instance of an class (monobehaviour). Static information is shared between all instances of the class and thus cannot be serialized by unity.

Additionally, do not put a constructor in your monobehaviours, the object is constructed by the unity engine using its own process and the awake function is called automatically. You're getting that null reference exception because the awake function is being called from your constructor and not from unities internal functions that are supposed to be initializing it, so things that need to be set up for it haven't been.

You haven't said why you need static information serialized but if you're trying to use a singleton approach there are a couple simple methods for doing it in unity:

```
class MySingleton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int someDataA;
    [SerializeField] private int someDataB;

    public static MySingleton Instance
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public int SomeDataA
    {
        get
        {
            return someDataA;
        }
        set
        {
            someDataA = value;
        }
    }
    public int SomeDataB
    {
        get
        {
            return someDataB;
        }
        set
        {
            someDataB = value;
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
}
```

alternatively

```
class MySingleton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int someDataA;
    [SerializeField] private int someDataB;

    private static MySingleton instance;

    public static int SomeDataA
    {
        get
        {
            return instance.someDataA;
        }
        set
        {
            instance.someDataA = value;
        }
    }
    public static int SomeDataB
    {
        get
        {
            return instance.someDataB;
        }
        set
        {
            instance.someDataB = value;
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

In the first example you can access the current instance of the component by going MySingleton.Instance and access your properties and functions on it. In the second example the instance is kept private and all the properties and functions are made static so you can access them directly on MySingleton without needing to see the instance.