# Why static variables do not appear in Inspector in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, static, public, inspector

I have **Example.cs** which has attached to the **Main Camera**, and in the **Main Camera's Inspector** I just can see the `aPoint` appear. Both `aPoint` and `bPoint` are `public` but why `static` makes `bPoint` doesn't appear in the **Inspector**.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
public class Example : MonoBehavior
{
    public int aPoint;
    public static int bPoint;
}
```

Comment: Check this post, there are answers and comments that will help you with your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61572008/making-static-class-data-serializable

Comment: It is Unity's standard behavior that static variables aren't displayed in inspector. A workaround is to have no static public variable with always has the value of that static variable.

Comment: In short: Because they don't! See [Script serialization rules](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) .. why is that? Because it wouldn't make any sense.. Should all instances of that component display the same value? What if you change it in one -> it would need to be updated in all other places as well.. A `static` is not related to any instance of the type but rather the type itself... If Unity ever **would** want to add this the only place where it would make sense would be in the script meta file itself ^^